# Regex find, move, and replace

Tags: php, regex, applescript

I have quite a few markdown files that starts with a yaml pattern such as:

```
---  
title: Miniarchi  
postheaderimage:  
  -  
    img: Miniarchi-1.jpg  
    alt: Minimal Architecture  
class: center  
categories:  
  - Design  
tags:  
  - Architecture  
  - Illustration  
  - Miniarchi  
---
```

The portion that I'll be working on, and want to modify in all the files, is:

```
postheaderimage:  
  -  
    img: Miniarchi-1.jpg  
    alt: Minimal Architecture
```

What I want it look like is:

```
postheaderimage: Miniarchi-1.jpg  
alt: Minimal Architecture
```

I've thought of the logic (using regex) of how I think it should be done but I don't know how to implement it. This is what I've come up with:

- find \w+(-\w+)+.jpg [match the image file name i.e. Miniarchi-1.jpg in this case]
- store in variable $img
- find postheaderimage:
- replace with postheaderimage: $img
- find alt:\s\w.* [match the image alt i.e. Minimal Architecture in this case]
- store in variable $alt
- find \s{2}-\n\s{4}img:\s.{1,}\n\s{4}alt:\s.{1,} [match everything under postheaderimage:]
- replace with $alt

I think this can be solved using applescript, or maybe even php, but I don't know how.
If more information is needed that I haven't mentioned, please ask and I'll be happy to clarify.

Comment: If you want to process data written in a computer language, you don't need a regex but a parser. For YML, there are many parsers, so simply get one of those to process your files.

Comment: why don't you just find img: and replace as postheaderimage

Comment: @Steve Thanks. Didn't think about it that way.

Answer (score 0):

you asked for an Applescript and it was fun to solve this task with real pure Applescript:

```
set my_test_file to (path to desktop as string) & "TEST.txt"
tidyUpMyYamlFile(my_test_file)

on tidyUpMyYamlFile(yaml_path)
    -- accessing the file's contents, storing it to fh_content
    try
        set fh to open for access yaml_path
        set fh_content to (read fh)
        close access fh
    on error
        try
            close access fh
        end try
        return
    end try

    -- repairing the postheaderimage part 
    set otid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "postheaderimage:  
  -  
    img:"

    set textParts to text items of fh_content
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "postheaderimage:"
    set new_fh_content to textParts as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to otid

    set fh_content_Lines to paragraphs of new_fh_content

    -- repairing the indentation for the word alt: (after the postheaderimage-line only)
    repeat with lineNo from 1 to count fh_content_Lines
        set altOffset to offset of "alt:" in (item lineNo of fh_content_Lines)
        -- this line contains the word "alt:"
        if altOffset > 0 then
            try
                -- the line before starts with the word "postheaderimage:"
                if item (lineNo - 1) of fh_content_Lines starts with "postheaderimage:" then
                    set oldLineContent to item lineNo of fh_content_Lines
                    set item lineNo of fh_content_Lines to text altOffset thru -1 of oldLineContent
                end if
            end try
        end if
    end repeat

    -- building new file content, line endings defined by line feed (Ascii 10)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASCII character 10
    set new_fh_content to fh_content_Lines as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to otid

    -- writing the new content to the old file
    set fh to open for access yaml_path with write permission
    set eof fh to 0
    write new_fh_content to fh
    close access fh

end tidyUpMyYamlFile
```

Believe me, it's really fast! Please try with copies! The script overwrites the source files!

Comment: Thanks @ShooTerKo but I went with Steve's suggestion and did the modification. Thanks again.

Comment: No prob, it was a nice training and fun :-)